# SNMP query the network range for multiple OIDs

Tags: ubuntu, networking, terminal, snmp

I looked for any SNMP scanner tool for Linux that can SNMP query an IP range for multiple OIDs and return results (if found), but didn't find anything.

I have SNMP installed on Ubuntu, is it possible with **snmpget** command query the network range for multiple OIDs and retrieve MIB values?
Is it possible do this from terminal as single command?

For example, **snmpget** network range 10.40.70.1/24 for 4 OIDs (OID1, OID2, OID3, OID4).

Comment: If the OIDs are in the same tree, you might use `snmpwalk`, otherwise `snmpbulkget`. But afaik network ranges are not supported by snmp tools, as they only allow the definition of _one_ agent.

Comment: Yes, OIDs are in the same tree. But is it possible scan hosts from network range one by one, not multiple hosts at once? (not multi-threaded parallel scanning).

Comment: Well, in bash you can do `for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do host=10.40.70.$i; if (ping -q -c 1 $host >/dev/null); then snmpget -v2c -c public $host OID1 OID2 OID3 OID4; fi; done`. But that might bring you trouble with your network administrator...

Comment: Seems, it does not return anything. OIDs are separated just by spacing?

Comment: `man snmpget`says so... maybe remove the `>/dev/null`to see what's going on. Or instead of testing with `ping`you could immediately call `snmpget`: `for (( i=254; $i; i=$i-1 )) do host=10.40.70.$i; snmpget -v 2c -c public $host OID1 OID2 OID3 OID4; done`. And of course change the options of snmpget to match your needs (-v 2c and -c public is just an example)

Comment: My bad, script should be launched from Terminal. Both versions work, but 1st version not show scan progress, just returns target OID if found, so we don't have idea how many hosts still remain. 2nd version show `Timeout: No Response from 10.40.70.254.` for every host, starting from the last one, so I can see how many hosts still remain. Works very slow (26 min scan time, 254 hosts) but did exactly what it should do. How to adjust that script not exit automatically after last host finished?

Comment: You could add `-t 0.5 -r 1` to the `snmpget` options; this will return faster with `timeout` (but you might not catch all hosts this way). And be aware that the line suggested implies that all hosts have same snmp version and community. To keep a script from exiting at the end you may use `read`: `read -p 'press enter to continue...' answer`

Comment: One note: how to modify code for subnet mask prefix length 16? (for example, in network address space 10.40.70.1/16)

Comment: Don't do that. You could of course make nested loops (for i.. for j...), but this means running against 65535 hosts - about 20 hours only for the timeouts; lots of network traffic; and possibly a blocked client, depending on the security of the network. Some software could think this is sort of attack. If it is your network, you should already know which nodes respond to SNMP.

Comment: Alternatively, how to run `snmpset` (single OID) against ip range 10.40.70.1/24, and if found host and value set successfully, return ip?

Comment: You know what community is allowed to write to all of your SNMP enabled hosts? If yes, there is something really wrong with your network security - or you are the network administrator, but then you should know what you're doing!

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can do something like:

```
for host in 10.40.70.{1..254}; do
  snmpget -v2c -c public $host OID1 OID2 OID3 OID4
done
```

You can use `{a..z}` or `{a,b,c}` ranges in place of multiple digits.

Comment: Can you clarify about specifying ranges for private networks Class A?

Comment: It's possible to do something like `for ip in 10.{0..255}.{0..255}.{0..255}; do snmpget ....; done`, but it will take a long time to scan 16 million IP addresses, particularly if most of them time out.

Comment: sure, no need to scan 16 million IP addresses, when possible to use target range `10.40.70.{1..254};`